# Microsoft Graph send mail function has started intermittently returning 200 status

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

My organisation uses Microsoft Graph and the /me/sendMail endpoint to send emails out from our system. It normally works perfectly, but as of this week, we have started to get intermittent errors where the request is returning a '200' status code, and the email is not being sent. Usually the code is 202 and then the mail comes through and is saved into the sent folder.
Does anyone know of a reason which might cause this, and how to fix it? We've studied the graph response object, and it sheds no light on any further errors. I don't think I can share that full response here, but if anyone knows a specific value to look for, I'll post what I find.

In examining the headers returned between a successful and unsuccessful request, I've noted the following differences.

The unsuccessful attempt had a Content-Length header and this was 0

Then the successful attempt had the following headers, which weren't present on the unsuccessful one:
Cache-Control, Transfer-Encoding, request-id, client-request-id and x-ms-ags-diagnostic

Then the rest of the headers were about the same, the baseurl is listed as https://graph.microsoft.com/ and the end point as /me/sendmail. Token is the same

Comment: as you said that intermittent errors, is it possible that your request is correct but the target email address is invalid?

Comment: Thanks for the response. No unfortunately it is to the same email addresses often. Basically a lot of emails are sent internally from our application to update administrators on what is happening. These email addresses don't change, but sometimes we get a 202 status and all is fine, other times the 200 and nothing further happens. And it used to work fine

Comment: I think we need further checking on this case, as this api but not sdk, there are no compatibility and version issues. I mean what we can take into consideration is the differences between the failed one and succeed one.

Comment: Did you get any progress sir? https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7MsR.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had the same problem and it seems that the issue was caused by the email attachment which was too big (exceeded 3MB). I've been getting HTTP 200 response for such emails with no additional info and like in your case those emails have not been sent at all.

For those where the attachments were small (up to Kb) all was fine.

Comment: Yes it seems this was the case for us as well. The file sizes had changed just slightly and it sent us over the 3 megabyte limit. This limit is really not documented very well, especially considering a normal email attachment size is bigger!

Answer (score 0):

We have tried out with both the below POST request in our environment as in below screen shot. Also with both V1.0 and Beta version and all seems to be working fine and provide us 202 Accepted. It shows there is no issue or Bug from the MS Graph end.

POST /me/messages/{id}/send

POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/send

Please try with Other user ID as in "POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/send" and verify, if you are receiving the same 200 return code or a different one.

[image]

[image]

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

**Note:** If the issue is not resolved from above, Please reach out to Azure Support by clicking on (Help+Support) and creating a technical request to Azure for assisted support.

Comment: Yes, so the problem is that previously all emails were returning the 202 status and they were being sent. But as of this week, some emails are returning a 200 status but not being sent. The emails are not in the sent items folder and the recipient is not receiving them. The same email might be sent to a few people at once, and some will receive it, but one in the batch might not.

Comment: There are some cases where emails can be sent without creating a message in sent items. Resource would look like this

me/mailFolders('SentItems')/messages

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately in these cases, the recipient is also not receiving the email. It was working previously perfectly every time, but now it isn't and the only change we can pick up is that when the email is not being delivered the status we receive is a 200 only, not a 202 as it is when there is success. Nothing has changed in our implementation or application to account for this, so I am hoping someone may know of a recent change to Graph which might cause this situation.

Comment: I have edited my Answer with the Repro screen shot with MS Graph V1.0 and Beta. Please refer to the Answer as it don't seem to be a Bug from our environment. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, I'll look into the details you have sent. The main reason I have raised it here, is that nothing on our environment changed, the email addresses were the same and the contents of emails were the same, but suddenly it stopped working randomly, so I am trying to ascertain what has changed.